# Some wired android behavior

Tags: android

I'm using the misc widgets panel control, so I got a reference to a library project.

Most of the times I have no problem but, sometimes (after rebuild) I get the following error

```
06-06 18:25:00.053: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dilbord/com.dilbord.ui.GroupedDealsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class org.miscwidgets.widget.Panel
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class org.miscwidgets.widget.Panel
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:800)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:729)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:271)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
    at com.dilbord.ui.GroupedDealsActivity.onCreate(GroupedDealsActivity.java:87)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
    ... 11 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
    ... 27 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.miscwidgets.R$styleable
    at org.miscwidgets.widget.Panel.<init>(Panel.java:85)
    ... 30 more
```

So the problem is with the R.stylable, but I have no idea how to avoid it and why is this happens.

I also use the amazing list view library, facebook sdk, segmented button library.

Any thought, Ideas?

Comment: `org.miscwidgets.widget.Panel` your Panel.java class path is right ?

Comment: post layout file for GroupedDealsActivity.java that you used